# "There doesn't seem to be a wp-config.php file." despite wp-config.php in root

Tags: errors, blog, wp-config

I've encountered an odd problem and I'm not at all sure how to go about fixing it..

I have [a site](http://parlourdc.com) that was working fine until I changed a page title from "PRESS" to "BLOG." Now, when you visit the [blog page](http://parlourdc.com/blog), this error comes up:

> There doesn't seem to be a wp-config.php file. I need this before we
>   can get started. Need more help? We got it. You can create a
>   wp-config.php file through a web interface, but this doesn't work for
>   all server setups. The safest way is to manually create the file.

What's especially odd about this is, both wp-config.php and wp-config-sample.php are in the site root. Any ideas what's going on and how to remedy?

Thank you.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "changed page title"? Where are WordPress files located in your site? Are they in same place as `wp-config.php`? Can you still access admin?

Comment: By "changed page title" I mean I had a page originally named "Press" and changed it(and it's slug) to "Blog".

I believe the files are located one level below wp-config.php(which is normal?). And yes, I can still access admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 WordPress installations. One for the main site, other for the Blog.

`http://parlourdc.com/wp-content/plugins/akismet/readme.txt`

`http://parlourdc.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/akismet/readme.txt`

If that's not on purpose, you have a `blog` folder in your site root that should be renamed/deleted as it contains a blank WordPress.

If you made a page on your main site titled Blog (and with `blog` slug), then change its slug and see what happens.

Comment: Interesting. The host setup for this particular site has had a lot of weird "kinks" in it, and this appears to be another. I deleted the `blog` folder per your direction, and everything works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you have phisicaly **blog** directory? and even if yes its strange becouse that a not bug problem if file wp-config.php located one level above the wp install.